# Multiple Instances of my Android Activity when launched via Scheme URL

Tags: android

I'm seeing a second instance of my launcher activity when I launch my app via URL. I've tried using singleInstance as launchMode which does prevent another instance from being created but it also has some nasty side effects.

One side effect is:

1. Launch my app via the icon
2. Open another activity from the main menu.
3. Click home button.
4. Launch my app again via the icon
5. The mainmenu is shown again and not the activity I was previously viewing.

I know this expected behaviour as I have looked at launchmodes in the Android docs.

My question is, is there any other way of preventing single instance of my activity without using singleInstance launchmode?

If I HAVE to use singleInstance, how can I retain the activity backstack when I relaunch the application?

Below is a portion of my manifest showing the mainmenu activity without the

```
<activity android:name="com.me.myapp.MainMenuActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<data
android:host="mydomain.com" android:scheme="http" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I've tried adding isTaskRoot to MainMenuActivity but this always return true when I can clearly see another running instance of the activity.

After some playing about, I've noticed:

1. I don't see a second instance if I use a single method to launch my app ie. clicking on a URL or using the launcher icon.
2. I ONLY see a second instance appear when I launch my app using/mixing both methods.

This suggests that the launch methods via URL and icon click are different. When an instance of my activity is already running and a new one is launched, onCreate is being called. This creates a new activity - I would like onNewIntent be called instead.

Comment: "A second instance of my app is launched when I launch it via URL" -- no, it is not. There is only one copy of your app. There will be a second instance of the *activity*.

Comment: Whoever editted my question hasn't done the greatest job.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using `singleTask` but I was still seeing two instances of my app.

I then stumbled across a blogpost [Android singleTask LaunchMode](https://lilpickle3000.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/android-singletask-launchmode/). It stated that `singleTask` activities cannot have `<intent-filter>`.

So I implemented a launcher activity, and now my app behaves correctly.